# Can I make a high frequency DC-DC SPMS boost converter with an SiC MOSFET?

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, high-voltage, boost, high-frequency

I am trying to design a boost converter.

The specifications are:

1. Vin = 100 V
2. Vout = 200 V
3. Iout = 1 A
4. Fsw = 5MHz
5. duty cycle = 50%

I tried with LTspice but some new parts do not have models, so the simulation is far from reality.

What can I adjust?

[image]

[image]

The voltage seems too high

And I want to speed up the ascent and reach steady state faster, what should I do?

[image]

Comment: You ask what you did wrong, but you don't say what the problem is.

Comment: `so the simulation is far from reality.` put some waveforms and measurements. What did you expect, and what did you get?

Comment: If you're referring to the simulation, it may be because you haven't connected the Tj, Tc pins; consult the model documentation to see proper usage.

Comment: I added new data and questions

Comment: @hardstudy your edit invalidates my answer. So I'm deleting it. You may want to go for a 2-stage solution i.e. first convert 100V to 200V *then* think about switching this 200V to your load with some frequency.

Comment: Why you think you need 5Mhz ? Using 500 or 200 kHz will reduce dramatically the switching losses and improve the efficiency of the SMPS

Comment: @RohatKılıç Thank your answer ,can I use this circuit to boost my voltage?

Comment: @matzeri My goal is that the frequency is as fast as possible, at least 1MHz or above.

Comment: increasing the frequency is not a target by itself, it is a tool to obtain something. What are your design target ? Efficiency, space ?

Comment: @matzeri do EDM test . I want to design high frequency model.